# SSH DB backup with dynamic filename with date

Tags: ssh, cron

Hello I am trying to backup a DB using an SSH/cron, everything works fine except I want to use a current date stamp within the command line so my backup file has a different name every time.

Does any one know how to include the date at the moment it is taking the text literally?

```
myDATE=date +%Y-%m-%d; 

mysqldump mydbname | gzip > /home/mywebsite/vps_backups/my_db_back_${myDATE}.sql.gz;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `crontab`, the `%` character have to be backslashed.

```
* * * * * command &> log_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H_\%M)
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/043

Comment: You should accept the question if it was helpful, to help people searching there that this question was answered. You can upvote too ;)

Comment: Accept mean to click on the green mark on the left of the reply ;) To upvote, you have the arrows on the left of the reply too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following syntax:

```
myDATE=$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)
```